# Raspberry pi 3 GPIO stopped working

Tags: gpio

I am creating a Paino with 28 notes.
I had everything working fine.
Then I added a small update for the code and it stopped working. Even the after the changes a basic button press script is not working.
Changed the SD card to a new Raspberry pi and the basic button press is not working.
I am working with pull down.
Here is the code that was working before but is not now.

```
import RPi.GPIO as IO
import pygame as pg

dir = '/home/pi/Desktop/sounds/'
busy = True
    print("Initializing")

pg.init()
mx = pg.mixer
mx.init()
print("Setting up channels")
mx.set_num_channels(29)

print("Assigning Channel Sounds")
print("Assinging Channel Pins")
k1 = 14
c1 = mx.Channel(1)
a1 = mx.Sound(dir+'A1.ogg')

k2 = 15
c2 = mx.Channel(2)
a2 = mx.Sound(dir+'A3.ogg')

k3 = 18
c3 = mx.Channel(3)
a3 = mx.Sound(dir+'A5.ogg')

k4 = 23
c4 = mx.Channel(4)
a4 = mx.Sound(dir+'A7.ogg')

k5 = 24
c5 = mx.Channel(5)
a5 = mx.Sound(dir+'E1.ogg')

k6 = 25
c6 = mx.Channel(6)
a6 = mx.Sound(dir+'F1.ogg')

k7 = 8
c7 = mx.Channel(7)
a7 = mx.Sound(dir+'G1.ogg')

k8 = 7
c8 = mx.Channel(8)
a8 = mx.Sound(dir+'A2.ogg')

k9 = 1
c9 = mx.Channel(9)
a9 = mx.Sound(dir+'B2.ogg')

k10 = 12
c10 = mx.Channel(10)
a10 = mx.Sound(dir+'C2.ogg')

k11 = 16
c11 = mx.Channel(11)
a11 = mx.Sound(dir+'D2.ogg')

k12 = 20
c12 = mx.Channel(12)
a12 = mx.Sound(dir+'E2.ogg')

k13 = 21
c13 = mx.Channel(13)
a13 = mx.Sound(dir+'F2.ogg')

k14 = 2
c14 = mx.Channel(14)
a14 = mx.Sound(dir+'G2.ogg')

k15 = 3
c15 = mx.Channel(15)
a15 = mx.Sound(dir+'A3.ogg')

k16 = 4
c16 = mx.Channel(16)
a16 = mx.Sound(dir+'B3.ogg')

k17 = 17
c17 = mx.Channel(17)
a17 = mx.Sound(dir+'C3.ogg')

k18 = 27
c18 = mx.Channel(18)
a18 = mx.Sound(dir+'D3.ogg')

k19 = 22
c19 = mx.Channel(19)
a19 = mx.Sound(dir+'E3.ogg')

k20 = 10
c20 = mx.Channel(20)
a20 = mx.Sound(dir+'F3.ogg')

k21 = 9
c21 = mx.Channel(21)
a21 = mx.Sound(dir+'G3.ogg')

k22 = 11
c22 = mx.Channel(22)
a22 = mx.Sound(dir+'A4.ogg')

k23 = 0
c23 = mx.Channel(23)
a23 = mx.Sound(dir+'B4.ogg')

k24 = 5
c24 = mx.Channel(24)
a24 = mx.Sound(dir+'C4.ogg')

k25 = 6
c25 = mx.Channel(25)
a25 = mx.Sound(dir+'D4.ogg')

k26 = 13
c26 = mx.Channel(26)
a26 = mx.Sound(dir+'E4.ogg')

k27 = 19
c27 = mx.Channel(27)
a27 = mx.Sound(dir+'F4.ogg')

k28 = 26
c28 = mx.Channel(28)
a28 = mx.Sound(dir+'G4.ogg')

print("configuring inputs")
IO.setmode(IO.BCM)

IO.setup(k1, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k2, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k3, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k4, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k5, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k6, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k7, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k8, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k9, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k10, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k11, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k12, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k13, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k14, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k15, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k16, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k17, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k18, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k19, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k20, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k21, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k22, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k23, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k24, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k25, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k26, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k27, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)
IO.setup(k28, IO.IN, pull_up_down = IO.PUD_DOWN)

print("Ready")

while busy:

    if IO.input(k1):
        if not c1.get_busy():
            c1.play(a1)
        print("k1")


    if IO.input(k2):
        if not c2.get_busy():
            c2.play(a2)
        print("k2")


    if IO.input(k3):
        if not c3.get_busy():
            c3.play(a3)
        print("k3")

    if IO.input(k4):
        if not c4.get_busy():
            c4.play(a4)
        print("k4")

    if IO.input(k5):
        if not c5.get_busy():
            c5.play(a5)
        print("k5")

    if IO.input(k6):
        if not c6.get_busy():
            c6.play(a6)
        print("k6")

    if IO.input(k7):
        if not c7.get_busy():
            c7.play(a7)
        print("k7")

    if IO.input(k8):
        if not c8.get_busy():
            c8.play(a8)
        print("k8")

    if IO.input(k9):
        if not c9.get_busy():
            c9.play(a9)
        print("k9")

    if IO.input(k10):
        if not c10.get_busy():
            c10.play(a10)
        print("k10")

    if IO.input(k11):
        if not c11.get_busy():
            c11.play(a11)
        print("k11")

    if IO.input(k12):
        if not c12.get_busy():
            c12.play(a12)
        print("k12")

    if IO.input(k13):
        if not c13.get_busy():
            c13.play(a13)
        print("k13")

    if not IO.input(k14):
        if not c14.get_busy():
            c14.play(a14)
        print("k14")

    if not IO.input(k15):
        if not c15.get_busy():
           c15.play(a15)
        print("k15")

    if IO.input(k16):
        if not c16.get_busy():
            c16.play(a16)
        print("k16")

    if IO.input(k17):
        if not c17.get_busy():
            c17.play(a17)
        print("k17")

    if IO.input(k18):
        if not c18.get_busy():
            c18.play(a18)
        print("k18")

    if IO.input(k19):
        if not c19.get_busy():
            c19.play(a19)
        print("k19")

    if IO.input(k20):
        if not c20.get_busy():
            c20.play(a20)
        print("k20")

    if IO.input(k21):
        if not c21.get_busy():
            c21.play(a21)
        print("k21")

    if IO.input(k22):
        if not c22.get_busy():
            c22.play(a22)
            print("k22")

    if IO.input(k23):
        if not c23.get_busy():
            c23.play(a23)
        print("k23")

    if IO.input(k24):
        if not c24.get_busy():
            c24.play(a24)
        print("k24")

    if IO.input(k25):
        if not c25.get_busy():
            c25.play(a25)
        print("k25")

    if IO.input(k26):
        if not c26.get_busy():
            c26.play(a26)
        print("k26")

    if IO.input(k27):
        if not c27.get_busy():
            c27.play(a27)
        print("k27")

    if IO.input(k28):
        if not c28.get_busy():
            c28.play(a28)
        print("k28")



print("done")
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware 26 inputs are available on the Pi3 GPIO.

These are BCM codes :
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio-plus-and-raspi2/

I commented out all buttons except k17 in your code and tested that with a button and 220ohm resistor connected to BCM17 and 3.3v. I changed the play to a print (as i don't have the .ogg files) and the code worked.

Comment: GPIO 0-27 are available on Pis with the 40 pin expansion header (which includes the Pi3).

Comment: Ok, it seems you can access 26 inputs https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio-plus-and-raspi2/ (not 0 or 1 - eeprom usage!)

Comment: Updated my answer based on 26 inputs

Comment: I'd class 0 and 1 as reserved.  If no HAT is present you can use 0 and 1 as you want.  However if there is a HAT attached there might be a conflict.